# Resharper not finding resource files in razor templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, resharper

Is it possible to use the ReSharper refactorisation "Move to Resource" from Razor views to resource files in the project (and not in the App_GlobalResources/App_LocalResources folders)?

From C#, I get the option to move resource strings to my project resource files, but from Razor views, I only have the option of moving to resource files in the aspnet special resources folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had the wrong accessibility level on the resource. It was internal, and as Razor views are compiled to a different assembly, they did not have access to my resources.

Comment: please explain further what you did. You say it was internal. What was and where can I find it. Did you just make it public? Did you change it the code or in a property window? Thanks.

Comment: As has been commented, it would be helpful to explain what you did to fix the issue, not just what the problem was.  -1 for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on another [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35793391)

> Open the .resx file with your "Managed Resource Editor" (the default),
>   look at the top of the screen. There's a dropdown called "Access
>   Modifier". Set it to public. Done.

Comment: A had the same problem with WinForms resources. This fixed it - Thanks