# Cannot get Reharper 9.1 Move to Resource refactoring to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, resharper

I get this error message when I try to apply the Move to Reource refactoring to a string in a razor file:

"This project does not contain an available resource file"

I have tried added ressource files by adding new item, and also by adding in the project settings dialog. and building etc. All to no help. What is the problem?

I am using JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2015.1.1 Build 102.0.20150521.123255
ReSharper 9.1.20150521.134223
in Visual Studio 2015 rc in an ASp.NET MVC 5 project.

Any suggestions how to make this refactoring to work?

Answer (score 6):

Open the .resx file with your "Managed Resource Editor" (the default), look at the top of the screen. There's a dropdown called "Access Modifier". Set it to public. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Bart Van Meerbeeck's answer didn't work for me for the identical issue, though it definitely is the best answer. In **MY** case, however, the problem was *me*.

I was working in a large solution, and the file, in which I was attempting to do this refactoring, was located within a completely different project than where my Solution Explorer was scrolled to at the time. Upon realizing this, I created the resources file in the respective project, and all was well.

So, to others who may run into this, simply click your "Sync with Active Document" button in Solution Explorer, to jump to the project for which file you're editing, and you won't feel dumb like I do. :)